# Fixing Riverpod from StateNotifier to NotifierProvider and app lifecycle monitoring

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

I'm using Riverpod in Flutter, and recently I've been migrating from StateNotifierProvider to NotifierProvider. As part of the migration, I made modifications to the Riverpod code that monitors the app's lifecycle and automatically changes the Flutter app's theme when the appearance mode of the app changes. I have a question regarding this modification.

Before the modification:

```
final sampleProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<SampleNotifier, SampleState>((ref) {
  final observer = SampleNotifier();
  final binding = WidgetsBinding.instance..addObserver(observer);
  ref.onDispose(() {
    binding.removeObserver(observer);
  });
  return observer;
});
```

After the modification:

```
final sampleProvider =
    NotifierProvider.autoDispose<SampleNotifier, SampleState>(() {
  final observer = SampleNotifier();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(observer);
  //final binding = WidgetsBinding.instance..addObserver(observer);
  // ref.onDispose(() {
  //   binding.removeObserver(observer);
  // });
  return observer;
});
```

In this modification from StateNotifierProvider to NotifierProvider, I removed the following part:

```
  ref.onDispose(() {
    binding.removeObserver(observer);
  });
```

Is it okay to remove this part? Will it have any negative impact or cause inefficiency in the app if the observer keeps getting bound indefinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you removed the disposal logic since you do not have access to the `ref` object.

In the new `Notifier` class, you can handle the initialisation and disposal logic inside the build method of `SampleNotifier`.

```dart
class SampleNotifier extends Notifier<SampleState> with WidgetsBindingObserver{
  @override
  SampleState build() {
    final binding = WidgetsBinding.instance..addObserver(this);
    ref.onDispose(() {
      binding.removeObserver(this);
    });

    return ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: thnks!!!!!!!!!!